# ByteBuffer - difference between encoding string and put vs CharSet encode?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

I have two different ways to create `ByteBuffer` object from String:

1. Get `byte[]` from String an use `ByteBuffer.put(byte[])` method:

```
private ByteBuffer respWithPut() {
    ByteBuffer respBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    respBuf.put(httpResponse().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    return respBuf;
}
```

2. Use `Charset.encode(String)` method:

```
private ByteBuffer respFromChar() {
    return StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.encode(httpResponse());
}
```

I am trying to send a simple HTTP response using this (complete code at the end of the question). With `respWithPut()` I get corrupted response on client, while `respFromChar()` works fine.

What am I doing wrong in `respWithPut()`?

**Complete Sample Code:**

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class AsyncServer {
    final String HTTP_DELIM = "\r\n";

    private String httpResponse() {
        String body = "HELLO";
        String prologue = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";
        String header = String.join(HTTP_DELIM,
                Arrays.asList(
                        "Date: " + Instant.now().toString(),
                        "Content-Type: text/plain",
                        String.format("Content-Length: %d", body.length()),
                        HTTP_DELIM
                )
        );
        return prologue + HTTP_DELIM + header +body;
    }

    private ByteBuffer respWithPut() {
        ByteBuffer respBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        respBuf.put(httpResponse().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
        return respBuf;
    }

    private ByteBuffer respFromChar() {
        return StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.encode(httpResponse());
    }

    public void startHttpServer() throws Exception {
        AsynchronousServerSocketChannel listener
                = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080));
        while (true) {
            Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> asyncCh = listener.accept();
            AsynchronousSocketChannel aSock = asyncCh.get();
            aSock.write(respWithPut());
            aSock.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AsyncServer asyncServer = new AsyncServer();
        asyncServer.startHttpServer();
    }
}
```

To make a sample request, use: `curl -v "http://localhost:8080/"`.

Comment: A ByteBuffer has a [position](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28%29) indicating where the next byte should be read from.  Your respWithPut method needs to call [respBuf.flip()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#flip%28%29) to make sure the buffer’s position is pointing to the data you just put in it.

Comment: @VGR this should be the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ByteBuffer has a [position](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28%29) indicating where the next byte should be read from. Your respWithPut method needs to call [respBuf.flip()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#flip%28%29) to make sure the buffer’s position is pointing to the data you just put in it.

After `ByteBuffer.allocate`:

```
position                              limit
↓                                     ↓
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_| … |_|
0 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 1 1 1 1     ↑
                      0 1 2 3 4 5     buffer size
```

After calling `ByteBuffer.put` with, for example, a byte array of length eight:

```
                  position            limit
                  ↓                   ↓
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_| … |_|
0 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 1 1 1 1     ↑
                      0 1 2 3 4 5     buffer size
```

The next `ByteBuffer.get` call will read the byte at index 8, which is still zero since you haven’t used `put` to add any data there.

After calling `ByteBuffer.flip`, the limit will be the old position, and the new position will be zero, making any existing data ready for reading:

```
next get operation will read from here
↓
position          limit
↓                 ↓
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_| … |_|
0 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 1 1 1 1     ↑
                      0 1 2 3 4 5     buffer size
```